# How do I show video content when Content Security Policy is in place?

Tags: content-security-policy

I am hoping that there is an easy answer to this one.

I am embedding a video from Vimeo on a page using the "fancybox" tools. Fancybox essentially creates an iFrame and embeds the Vimeo player.  It works great in all browsers - until I turn Content Security Policy on.  Then ID works (since it doesn't implement CSP) but Chrome and Firefox just hang with the "loading" image shown.

I've tried this CSP:

```
<add header="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self'; media-src 'self' http://player.vimeo.com; frame-src 'self' http://player.vimeo.com; " />
<add header="X-Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self'; media-src 'self' http://player.vimeo.com; frame-src 'self' http://player.vimeo.com; " />
<add header="X-WebKit-CSP" value="default-src 'self'; media-src 'self' http://player.vimeo.com; frame-src 'self' http://player.vimeo.com; " />
```

The thinking, of course, is that I am permitting both media and my iframe to come from vimeo.  But it doesn't work.  Does anyone know why?

UPDATE: I removed CSP for just the page showing video and looked at the content with Google's developer tools.  I turns out that Vimeo brings in a ton of other stuff from other Vimeo sub-domains, vimeocdn.com, conviva.com, lphbs.com, and even Amazon's aws.  So - if you use Vimeo (and YouTube?) you either have a very long list of external sites or you just don't use CSP?  Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: It would be great to see the full solution to this problem. So you ended up adding a long list of headers for each of Vimeo's URLs? Or you turned off CSP?

Comment: You should set a report-uri to let the browsers report CSP violations to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the best option is to add the long list of hosts, but don't remove CSP!

Based on your policy, removing CSP would mean the following:

- You're allowing inline script as well as dangerous calls to eval - essentially opening up another opportunity for reflected/stored XSS
- Frames can be injected from anywhere
- Images, styles, applets, etc can be loaded from anywhere.

Often times you'll need to allow inline script/evals, but a content security policy is still very valid.

You can also use the report-only form of the header in conjunction with report-uri in order to collect a list of the possible places you would need to whitelist.

Comment: Thanks Oreoshake.  I wrote my header rule to just exclude the Video page.  Since this is a straight 'output only' page where no user can contribute comments, etc. I'm safe not worrying about CSP here.  Thanks for the tip on getting the full list.